# Hide a string in a file before git commit

Tags: svn, git, version-control, hook

I would like a specific string in a specific file to be hidden every time I commit changes to that file.

Actually, I have a URL in a file that shouldn't be public in a remote repository. Is there anyway to hide it using pre-commit and post-commit hooks or something similar?

Currently I am working with a git repository but it would be nice to know how to do this with svn.

Thanks,
Simão

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must have that file under version control, use a [git attribute filter driver](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (see also [GitPro book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)).

> A filter driver consists of a `clean` command and a `smudge` command, either of which can be left unspecified.
>   Upon `checkout`, when the `smudge` command is specified, the command is fed the blob object from its standard input, and its standard output is used to update the worktree file.
>   Similarly, the `clean` command is used to convert the contents of worktree file upon check-in.

That way, the script (**a private version, only in your repo, not managed by Git**) referenced by the smudge can replace the coded URL, while the clean script will restore its content to a coded URL.
A public version of the same script, managed by git and pushed everywhere would do... nothing and keep the URL obfuscated.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could keep that string in a separate file (such as a resource file, if your environment supports that), and not put that file under version control.

Comment: I would do this as well. It's cleaner both in terms of not having to use git hooks and in having a central place to store sensitive information.

Comment: +1. That would be the easiest way, both for the source control system, and for maintaining installation-specific settings. But at least with git, there should be a way to make the original plan work, because git (unlike svn) allows partial file commits.

Comment: Yes, actually a simple solution like this would work. Thanks :)