# Using a single visual studio 2005 solution with multiple source control applications

Tags: git, visual-studio-2005, version-control, clearcase

In my recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342131/how-to-bridge-git-to-clearcase) I was helped tremendously in using git as a front-end to ClearCase. However actually trying the suggested answer(s) led to further complications. Visual Studio keeps a reference to the used source control provider in both the `.sln` as well as the `.csproj` files. I tried resolving this issue by keeping a modified copy of the `.sln` with the source control provider paragraph removed but this did not help since each project also has some source control provider information. I don't want to keep *private* copies of all the projects since this would be a maintenance nightmare. Do any of you have suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for this kind of config file (which need to be kept into source control), we also version a script able to change them in order to put the right data (the right username, ip address, local path, ...) in them.

With Git in particular, that allows you to define a **[smudge/clean process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293383/hide-a-string-in-a-file-before-git-commit/2294246#2294246)** which will do just that automatically when filling a working tree, whereas a commit will store the same config file with its original content.
See also "[How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project/2155355#2155355)".

[image]

So in your case, while a "cleartool update" will download in your snapshot view some `.sln` and `.csproj` with specific content (incorrect in your context), a git checkout of the same working directory (directly embedded within your snapshot view) will trigger the smudge process, running a script of your choice in order to update the content of said files with adequate informations.