# With git, temporary exclude a changed tracked file from commit in command line

Tags: git

I have a **tracked** database (already added) file in git. I want this file to always contain the same data in my git repository. Even when I modify it in the working copy (local sandbox) for test purposes.

With git, how to exclude this changed file on my working copy from a commit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way to ignore certain files that are already committed is

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file
```

However, this is a local setting, and it doesn't propagate when cloning.

Its effect is canceled with `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged gui`.

Comment: This a local setting, that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Why `gui` and not `file`?

Comment: @jmd_dk `gui` instead of `file` looks just a typo. Should be `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file`

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to using `git add` I would suggest to use a shell with more capabilities, i.e. [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/). Here you can insert extended globbing like `*~*.o(.)` which means all files except such ending with `o`. This make it easier to add all files except one. Zsh also allows you to set a global alias: `alias -g AF="*~*.o(.)"`. So you can type `git add AF` and it will be expanded in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't do `git commit -a`, `git commit` will only commit files that you have explicitly added to the index using `git add`.

Comment: However, it's tedious to memorize, which files you should add, and which you should not.

Answer (score -1):

simply do not add it with `git add`, but add any other file you want to commit

then use `git commit` instead of `git commit -a`

Answer (score -2):

The smarter way to do this is to not track the database at all, directly. Track an example database and then each developer can copy it and modify it, and it can be under gitignore.

Comment: -1.  Not helpful.  Anyway, sometimes you can't do this because external framework **modifies** file during build, and can't generate it at the same time.

Comment: If my file is tracked, it is because it should be tracked...
It is just that I do not want to propagate the changes I make on a testing level.

Answer (score -3):

1. add this file to your repo
2. commit
3. add it to `.gitignore` file
4. commit `.gitignore` file

Comment: This makes my head hurt, but is probably more elegant than my suggestion

Comment: This solution does not work because the file is already tracked, is'n it?

Comment: -1. This just does not work.  The file is still shown in `git status` as modified.