# call .exe in git pre-commit hook on changed files

Tags: git, githooks

I have an application (.exe) I wrote which takes a file path and performs some custom formatting on the file passed in.  I would like to know if there's a way using git pre-commit hooks to pass in the changed files being committed to my .exe so they can be formatted before going to the git repository.  If so how?  I don't know php so if there's a way to do this using c# or .bat file I'd prefer this.  If there's a different better approach i'm open to that also.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the job for a content filter driver (a `clean` one), not a pre-commit hook.

See "[Protecting files in git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3360122/6309)": you can declare a script which will apply to only certain files, automatically on commit.

Comment: I read the post from your link thank you.  However, i don't see how i can leverage that information for what i'm trying to do.  Is it possible you could provide some more detail to help me out?

Comment: @johnsontroye I don't have much beside that post: the first step is to be able to write a script able to revert the custom formatting back to the original file content.