# is there a way to 'extend' svn command line to preprocess source files

Tags: git, svn

Problem: I need to check in some unfinished work so the team can start testing.  There is a bunch of stuff I don't want to commit.

This is no solution for either git or svn.

[Ignore specific changes to a file in git, but not the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598257/ignore-specific-changes-to-a-file-in-git-but-not-the-entire-file)

Hmm... I could implement this in a shell script, if there were a way to 'extend' svn to add 'preprocessor' shell scripting.

Basically, write a shell script that strips out lines bounded by a certain lexible symbol, just before executing 'svn commit'.

Off the top of my head:

```
#pragma mark nocommit
#pragma mark endnocommit
```

has anyone done this?

I put #warning's in my working copy that I don't need other people to see for many reasons.  However, when it comes time to commit, I have to laboriously edit out these notes, and then put them back in after the commit.

Examples:

- I've got a new feature working that you need the team to start testing, but I've marked up the code with a list of 'known bugs'.  I want these #warning's as a reminder to tell the tester not to worry about these 'known bugs'
- I've reproduced an edge-case bug, but I don't have time to fix it yet.
  Example:

  #warning known bug: figure out why this "ERROR: mismatch" happens when you drag/drop a clip?
- I put in a #warning to keep something on my radar because I haven't come up with a more elegant solution yet
- I don't want other team members to *know* that I haven't come up with a better solution yet, because once you commit a comment like this, people tend to interpret it as something 'official' they need to weigh in on.  (i.e. advice that I don't want to hear right now because of my passive-aggressive personality :P)

Example:

I would love to markup my working copy with something that git/svn/etc. will recognize as something I never want committed, like this:

```
#pragma mark nocommit
#warning TODO... figure out why this mismatch happens when you drag/drop a clip?
##pragma mark endnocommit
```

This would save me *soooooo* much time compared the other 'non-solutions' suggested.

Hmm... someone else suggested this:

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/30087865/dir/opensuse_13.x/com/perl-App-GitHooks-Plugin-BlockNOCOMMIT-1.0.2-4.1.noarch.rpm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git support some hooks as [explained here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). For your case a `pre-commit` hook seems appropriate. This hook runs on your local machine before you commit to your local clone.

The Subversion *clients* do not support hooks, only the Subversion server as explained [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.html). Adding this kind of hooks on a central server is usually not done lightly. Therefore for SVN you can wrap the `svn` client with a shell-script wrapper which intercepts `svn ci` and similar stuff and performs your checks. But this is easily bypassed for examples by IDEs which use the SVN API directly.

Comment: good info, thanks.  yeah to do this for subversion *client* looks hard/impossible, since 'svn commit' doesn't support --dry-run option