# Per-worktree local exclusion

Tags: git, git-worktree

I'd like to use local file exclusion on a [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). I tried adding the file name to `.git/worktrees/$worktreename/info/exclude` but it doesn't take. The analogous file `.git/info/exclude` works, but applies to all worktrees, not just the main one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but it doesn't take

I do not see an `info/exclude` in [`.git/worktrees` official layout documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#gitrepository-layout-worktrees).

A workaround would to have a branch-specific `.gitignore` content.
That means adding your untracked file to the worktree `.gitignore` remains the best option.
And you can ignore modification on that (tracked) `.gitignore` file with the update-index command [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354629/6309).

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- .gitignore
```

That allows you for the *local* exclusion you are after.

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio. I was using Git 2.15 when I asked the question, but upgrading now to 2.16 didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @Cactus Then my comment about git/wortrees layout stands: there does not seem to be any .git/worktrees/info/exclude file managed by Git at the moment.

Comment: @Cactus Note that if by "local ignore" you mean ignore modification for an already tracked file, that would be done with a git update-index command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354629/6309. For an untracked file, adding it to the .gitignore remains the common solution.

Comment: no, that's not what I mean -- the behaviour I am after is exactly as if I had multiple independent repos instead of worktrees, each with its own `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: @Cactus So we are talking about untracked file, right?

Comment: yes, I am talking about untracked files that I don't want to show up in `git status` etc.

Comment: Another option would be to set per worktree, the config `core.excludesFile` in order to reference a different file on each worktree... but I do't think you can have more than one local config (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#gitrepository-layout-config)

Comment: So, adding your untracked file to the worktree .gitignore remains the best option. And you can ignore modification on that (tracked .gitignore file) with the update-index command I mentioned before in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354629/6309

Comment: can you edit your answer to contain the final conclusion, so I can accept it?

Comment: I solved this just by an adding entry to my global gitignore file. Yes, not quite as clean, but, it works great.