# Git: File that must be distributed, but ignored / not reuploaded?

Tags: git, repository, gitignore, git-clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

I have a simple problem, and I hope there's a simple solution.

Using Git (and Tower, great app), I have a repository that has a file that everyone needs to download when they clone the repo, BUT that file should never be reuploaded with changes (because it's a configurtion file, with database-specific usernames / passwords, and paths) - the changes are made only when used locally.

What I want to do is ignore whatever change I made locally to that file, so the file won't get updated when I push changes to my repo. How can this be achieved?

It should be noted that:

1. When I clone the repo, the file shows up, but when I ignore it (local only, not via .gitignore) I have to untrack it, and when I do and push changes back to the server, anyone that clones the repo will NOT download the file << undesired behavior.
2. If I ignore the file but I DON'T untrack it, the file still shows up in my working directory, waiting to be commited << undesired behavior.

Comment: Indeed. As stated in that link (useful BTW, thanks!) is using git update-index --assume-unchanged (thoroughly explained in here: http://goo.gl/UZi0E). From what I've seen though, there's no way to do this through Tower.app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Commit an example file, gitignore the real name, and have your contributors copy the example into the proper location, then configure it. Alternately, provide a setup script that copies the example and does those steps.

Comment: This is a good alternative too (since, in my app, there are not too many configuration files to modify, only 2) - I'm guessing that, for example, Moodle (config-dist.php) and Wordpress (wp-config-example.php, if I recall correctly) use this method in their respective version control systems.

Answer (score -3):

This is properly addressed with smudge/clean scripts.

Alternatively, scripts that do the deploy reset the user names and passwords.

Bending tracking and ignoring is not the way to solve this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Care to give an example? I'm fairly new to Git, so I don't really know what a smudge/clean script is. I also do not understand the "Alternatively, scripts that do the deploy reset the user names and passwords" part.