# Keep file in a Git repo, but don't track changes

Tags: git

I need to include some files in my GitHub repo, but not track changes on them. How can I accomplish this? An example use case is for a file that includes sensitive user information, such as login credentials.

For example, I deploy a new installation of this framework to a new client, I want the following files to be downloaded (they have default values CHANGEME) and I just have to make changes specific to this client (database credentials, email address info, custom CSS).

```
// The production config files. I want the files but they need to be updated to specific client needs
application/config/production/config.php
application/config/production/database.php
application/config/production/tank_auth.php
// Index page, defines the environment (production|development)
/index.php
// All of the css/js cache (keep the folder but not the contents)
/assets/cache/*
// Production user based styling (color, fonts etc) needs to be updated specific to client needs
/assets/frontend/css/user/frontend-user.css
```

Currently if I run

```
git clone git@github.com:user123/myRepo.git httpdocs
```

and then edit the files above, all is great. Until I release a hotfix or patch and run `git pull`. All of my changes are then overwritten.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: File that must be distributed, but ignored / not reuploaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586267/git-file-that-must-be-distributed-but-ignored-not-reuploaded)

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Comment: You could just ignore client credential/configuration files and have the program build default files if they are missing when the repo is installed?

Comment: Does anyone know why this obvious mechanism isn't well supported by git?

Answer (score 789, accepted):

git has a different solution to do this. First change the file you do not want to be tracked and use the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE_NAME
```

and if you want to track the changes again use this command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILE_NAME
```

[git-update-index documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Comment: I did what you say but git status keep telling the file is modified

Comment: Works just fine for me. Did you get a message saying "unable to mark file..." when you tried?

Comment: Works over here - finally my 2-stage deployment won't cause constant untracked changes. THANK YOU @nasirkhan !!!

Comment: As per Junio Hamano (the maintainer of Git):
"Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism. [...] it is not a promise by Git that Git will always consider these paths are unmodified---if Git can determine a path that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path has been modified (as a result, "git commit -a" is free to commit that change)."
In other words, assume-unchanged is just for local performance issues. If Git can determine that those files changed in a lighter way, it will.

Comment: If anybody else is using a GUI git client, you may need to restart it for it to stop tracking the file you ignored

Comment: Reading the info for it, I think the `--skip-worktree` option is better suited to this job than `--assume-unchanged`.

Comment: --skip-worktree is indeed the better option. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree#

Comment: nasirkhan, can you answer if this affects other users who pull? When I ran it, there was nothing to push

Comment: If you get a message like `fatal: unable to mark file...` it might mean that your file is already ignored (or yet added to the repo)

Answer (score 174):

To pull an answer out of the comments of another answer:

`$ git update-index --skip-worktree FILENAME`

Appears to be a better option than `--assume-unchanged`

More can be read about this here: [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree#)

Comment: Thanks. Also: [medium.com/@igloude/git-skip-worktree-and-how-i-used-to-hate-config-files](https://medium.com/@igloude/git-skip-worktree-and-how-i-used-to-hate-config-files-e84a44a8c859)

Comment: When I do this and then try to change branches,  I get "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout...Please move or remove them before you switch branches".  Any ideas how to avoid?

Comment: The article referenced by @aexl has moved to https://compiledsuccessfully.dev/git-skip-worktree/

Comment: The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes) say this is a bad idea.

"Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked. This does not work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against the index when performing certain operations. In general, Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate solutions are recommended."

Answer (score 68):

For my Code Igniter projects, I keep **database.php.example** and **config.php.example** in the repo.

Then I add **config.php** and **applications/config/database.php** to the **.gitignore** file.

So, finally, when I deploy, I can copy the .example files (to config.php and database.php), customize them, and they won't get tracked by GIT.

Comment: This is not a good solution. If you flush your git index you're going to start tracking changes when you don't mean to. See @nasirkhans answer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: I disagree with both previous comments. This way it's much easier to update the "default" values without having to checkout them and copy your local configuration elsewhere just to put it back after. Also, it applies to all repositories so you don't have to do any repeated repo-changes.

Comment: if it is in gitignore why would it start tracking changes again

Comment: Solves the OP's problem but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: from your answer, now I know what those .example is used for. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 21):

The recommended way, as of git version 2.25.1, is to track templates of the files in the repository, copying them into new files and modifying them locally (ignoring the new filename in `.gitignore`) ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/5449925)):

> Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to
> tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked. This does not
> work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against
> the index when performing certain operations. In general, Git does not
> provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate
> solutions are recommended.
>
> For example, if the file you want to change is some sort of config
> file, the repository can include a sample config file that can then be
> copied into the ignored name and modified. The repository can even
> include a script to treat the sample file as a template, modifying and
> copying it automatically.

Comment: Duplicating files is a reasonable solution.  The nature of the problem is that we're trying to maintain different versions of a file on different machines.  That is better modeled as completely different files -- one for each machine.  Unfortunately, if you need to reference the different file variant from some other common file, you're still stuck with the same problem of having a file that is different across machines.  But on the upside, the duplicate file templates create a self-documenting mechanism, and a breakage is less painful.

Comment: Upvoted as this is what i have been doing, and never had any issues. The other solutions (inexplicably with lots of upvotes) seem like an overly complicated way of making git even more of a wizard-art to use. End of the day, you want to track a file or you want to ignore it. Anyone can easily copy paste a file without reading git docs.

Answer (score 3):

I would put them in your `.gitignore` file and just copy them manually as needed.

So the skeleton filename would be in git, the ignore filenames would not be in git (but would be in .gitignore). That way, when the manual step to copy them to 'actual' from 'template' (better name than skeleton perhaps) is done they are immediately ignored.

Comment: theres no way to add them into the repo first, and then add them to .gitignore? It'd be great if there was a solution for this to include the files but not any changes after a certain commit or something.

Comment: @mklauber I want to keep them indefinitely until i run `git rm <file>`. The purpose is IE: a config.php file. I want to keep the config file but i obviously dont want to track the database credentials from client to client as they are different.

Comment: Yes, I have the issue with our rails database.yml file.  We keep a skeleton and then copy and change it.

Comment: if i create these "Skeleton" config files, would you be adding them to an initial commit. and then modifying .gitignore to ignore the file? In effect keeping the file in the repo but as a skeleton?

Comment: You have these two options: Add the file by `git add file1` and then edit your `.gitignore` file. The commited file will stay in there and not be updated. Or: You can add the file to `.gitignore` and then add it with `git add --force file1` to force the file in. You can use the 2nd option whenever you have to overwrite the file

Comment: skeleton filename would be in git, the ignore filenames would not be in git (but would be in git ignore).  That way, when the manual step to copy them to 'actual' from 'template' (better name than skeleton perhaps) is done they are immediately ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given are solving the problem just partially, but introducing even more problems.

I needed to preserve the"Web.Local.config" file.
The only solution that worked for me was to:

**1. Exclude the file from the project**

**2. Create a separate copy of the file as Web.LocalTemplate.config**

Now that "Web.LocalTemplate.config" is tracked by Git, all developers can use it as a starting point. However, the "Web.Local.config", not being part of the project will be automatically ignored.

Comment: How is `git update-index --skip-worktree FILENAME` only solving your problem partially, or even adding more problems?? It solves exactly what you're trying to do. Did you try it?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf `--skip-worktree` only works in the local repository (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451213), so each developer that clones the upstream repository would need to run that command. Which makes it a rather fragile approach unless you're the only developer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add "full path for filename" (relative path from root)

`git update-index --skip-worktree FILENAME`.

If you do not give the full path for the file. It will give an error

`fatal: Unable to mark file response.json`