# How to hide SVG diff in GitHub (Or show SVG as image)

Tags: git, svg, github

Recently we add SVG files to our Git repository frequently. The problem is SVG file diff is really annoying to see other diff on GitHub.

The diff is like this

```
+   <path class="st3" d="M179.7,29l-0.6-4c-0.1-0.7,0-1.3,0.4-2c1.5-2.8,2.6-6.2,3.4-10.3c0-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.6s0.5-0.2,0.8-0.1
+       l2.1,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8c-0.3,2.2-0.8,4.2-1.4,6c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3v18c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8
+       c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3h-2.1c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8V27.7c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1,0c-0.5,0.9-0.8,1.4-0.8,1.5
+       c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2C179.8,29.3,179.7,29.2,179.7,29z M207.8,26.7c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.3,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3h-0.4
+       c0,0,0,0-0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.9,1.4c0.2,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.7l-0.9,0.7
+       c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.5-0.8-1.3-1.6-2.3c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.2,0.6-0.7,0.9-1.4,1
+       c-0.7,0.1-2.2,0.2-4.4,0.2h-1.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0.1c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2s-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1,0,0.1h8
+       c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.8V32c0,0.8-0.3,1.3-0.8,1.8c-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.9-1.8,1.3c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1
+       c1.6,0.2,3.3,0.4,5.1,0.5c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.3s0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7l-0.4,1.5c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.7c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.2
+       c-3.2-0.3-6.2-0.9-9-1.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-2.7,0.9-5.6,1.5-8.8,1.9c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8-0.2c-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.7l-0.4-1.4
```

We want to track SVG files as image, but GitHub shows their diff as text.
Any way to hide these SVG file diff automatically? Or way to show them as image as default?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794931/keep-file-in-a-git-repo-but-dont-track-changes

Comment: Thanks. But we don't want to ignore files themselves. We need to track them but don't want to see diff as text.

Comment: Ah. To hide it in github, you might be able to try this [browser extension](https://github.com/matthewrobertson/Github-Collapse-Diff) for Chrome. Here are two in the Chrome store: [one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-diff-helper/dhggdgaoccikibijlbocggphcomehbih?hl=en), [two](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-collapse-diff/eenmpdlgpfhmgkkmpjmmchokkmjacaeo?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have tried this already and worked nicely. But now it's not maintained totally... (BTW I created a PR for that repo last year). Anyway I can use another Chrome extension thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be of more help. Perhaps someone else who knows github better than I do can provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub does not provide any way to ignore certain files in diffs. Perhaps one day (send a feature request!) they'll build an SVG viewer the way they did [for images](https://github.com/blog/817-behold-image-view-modes).

In the meantime, if you also store a rendered copy of your SVG in the repository, you could at least get both views. Credit [to HBHB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480883/how-to-hide-svg-diff-in-github-or-show-svg-as-image#comment54747168_33480883) for recommending the [Github diff helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-diff-helper/dhggdgaoccikibijlbocggphcomehbih?hl=en) and [Github Collapse Diff](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-collapse-diff/eenmpdlgpfhmgkkmpjmmchokkmjacaeo?hl=en) Chrome extensions too. Just pulling them out of the comments for better visibility.

Comment: What do you mean with "one day"? This was implemented way before this question was asked: https://github.com/blog/1902-svg-viewing-diffing

Comment: Still happy to find this in the next decade!

Answer (score 1):

Github now shows SVG and image previews on `Files Changed` section and its enabled by default:

[image]

And you can also hide/show files like this:

[image]