# git how to reserve a file both on remote and local, but don't track the modify of this file ever

Tags: git

In my case, l have a database config file `database.php` and a hook to deploy the project.

l need to modify the database.php to connect my local database, but l don't want to   push it to remote, because it will affect the dev env by hooking.

l tried to use `git rm --cached -r database.php` to untracked the file, but it will  delete this file at remote git server. so my dev server will also delete this file.

then, dev server BOOM.

l also tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged database.php`, but it is not suitable my case so well.

Comment: try --skip-worktree

Comment: @Gimhani yes, l tried it, l think it is working now. l will verify it more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you since it will skip tracking the changes for this file then onwards.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

This [little article](https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/ignore-changes-in-file-when-using-git/) and the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/4848659) here will help you.

Comment: so cool! but l still have a question. this project is a multi-person project. so, do they(other developers) also need execute this command?

Comment: i believe this only affects the local repository. so others too will need to do so.

Comment: @afraid.jpg have you tried updating the .gitignore once the file is already tracked.based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/35451148/4848659 , it too will be a solution.