# Using git, is there a way to say, just ignore the conflict and proceed with everything?

Tags: git

I use a few computers to work on a project and sync up the files quickly use `git push` and `git pull`.  There is a file `results.txt` which is nice to have, but not mandatory, and each machine may happen to have altered the file.

When we do `git pull` and `git push` and this file resulted in merge conflict, is there just a quick way to tell `git` to ignore the conflict and proceeed?  I think right now we need to `git add results.txt` and `git commit -a`. Is there a quick way just to keep one version or the other or even just use the conflict file and not worry about it? Or alternatively, is there a way to manage this file to work with git conflicts? I also thought of: if we use `resultsSample.txt` and it is part of the repo, and keep `results.txt` out of the repo and this is the file that our program outputs to, then it seems we could avoid the conflicts of the results, but just that at times we might want to copy `results.txt` to `resultsSample.txt` to update the content reasonably updated.

Comment: I would add it to the .gitignore file, such that the current version stays in the repo but is not updated

Comment: @FloLie .gitignore will not ignore changes to a committed file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794931/keep-file-in-a-git-repo-but-dont-track-changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull

Answer (score 2):

You can use git attributes to define a merge driver for the file. A simple merge driver that always keeps "our" version would be just using `/bin/true`:

```
git config --global merge.keep-ours.driver /bin/true
```

then add a `.gitattributes` in your repository:

```
results.txt merge=keep-ours
```