# Kotlin Multiplatform multi-project Gradle error: "Projects must be configuring"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project (1.7.10), with multiple subprojects, using Gradle 7.4.2. When running Gradle tasks I regularly get an error message from the Kotlin Gradle plugin:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':modules:web-map:publicPackageJson'.
> Error while evaluating property 'externalDependencies$kotlin_gradle_plugin' of task ':modules:web-map:publicPackageJson'
   > Projects must be configuring
```

The error will not go away, unless I somehow force the project to 'refresh'. So I can temporarily work around this by making an incidental edit to the root `build.gradle.kts`, for example changing

```kotlin
// $projectRoot/build.gradle.kts

println("annoying bug")
```

into

```kotlin
// $projectRoot/build.gradle.kts

//println("annoying bug")
```

This minor change somehow forces the Kotlin plugin to 'refresh', and I can then run the Gradle task again.... until the next time. The bug is very quick to re-occur.

There are several bug tickets opened, but they have been awaiting resolution for months.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49774
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50168
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52647

However this bug is incredibly frustrating, so I would like to have a work around.

I have already tried

- disable Gradle caching
- disable Gradle parallelization
- force the Kotlin Gradle tasks to always run, by adding a 'cache busting' Gradle task input to all tasks
- creating a Gradle task that will automatically edit `build.gradle.kts` before all tasks, to automate forcing the refresh.

Unfortunately nothing worked consistently.

An example project is available here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52647/KJS-Gradle-Make-Projects-must-be-configuring-a-warning#focus=Comments-27-6195302.0-0

Answer (score 0):

I have created a <strike>hack</strike> elegant temporary workaround.

I created a Gradle task, `projectsMustBeConfiguringBuster`, that will make an incidental edit to a Gradle script, and registered that task as a finalizer task of *all* other tasks. This somehow resets the Kotlin plugin so it thinks the project is 'configuring'.

To try and keep things clean, I created a new Gradle script, `kt52647.gradle.kts`, which I apply in the root `build.gradle.kts`. If you wanted, you could add this file to `.gitignore`, or commit it but then [tell Git to ignore any future changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410119/4161471).

```kotlin
// $projectRoot/build.gradle.kts

// ... other build settings ...

apply(from = "$projectDir/kt52647.gradle.kts")
```

```kotlin
// $projectRoot/kt52647.gradle.kts

val projectsMustBeConfiguringBuster by tasks.registering {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  val buildFile = rootProject.layout.projectDirectory.file("kt52647.gradle.kts").asFile
  doLast {
    logger.warn("Applying 'Projects must be configuring' workaround - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52647")

    val newLines = buildFile.readText().lines().joinToString("\n") { line ->
      if (line.startsWith("// projects must be configuring buster")) {
        "// projects must be configuring buster ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
      } else {
        line
      }
    }

    buildFile.writeText(newLines)
  }
}

allprojects {
  tasks
    .matching { it.name != projectsMustBeConfiguringBuster.name }
    .configureEach {
      finalizedBy(
        rootProject.tasks.matching { it.name == projectsMustBeConfiguringBuster.name }
      )
    }
}


// projects must be configuring buster 1664920329388
// ^ this line will be edited by projectsMustBeConfiguringBuster
```

I can now repeatedly run `./gradlew assemble` and I don't get an error.

If I comment out `finalizedBy(...)` I encounter the "Projects must be configuring" bug on the second `assemble` run.