# Different local version of file with Git

Tags: git

I work with a few colleagues on a Git project stored at Bitbucket. For one of the files I need to keep a different copy (it's a gulpfile and one job just won't run on my machine). Is there a chance for me to keep it from uploading – except that I manually exclude it from `git add`?

`.gitignore` is no solution because this file is synched too and the other team members want to keep updating their gulpfile. I tried .git/info/exclude, but this only seems to work unless the file is already in the archive.

Comment: you can ignore by using `update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>` http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Comment: You're both right - `update-index --assume-unchanged` did the trick. Thanks a lot!