# Personal git ignore not working

Tags: git

In GIT in the command line I see I have a modified file:

```
#   modified:   sites/sites.php
```

I want to not commit this, but I want this file to only be excluded locally. Ive opened the file called exclude in .git/info and added this line:

```
sites/sites.php
```

Ive reverted the modifications to the file so I have nothing to commit. Ive made the change again and it shows up in GIT in the terminal again as a change. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Will this affect the repo for other users? I need to only ignore local changes on one machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git ignore files only locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally)

Comment: @nwinkler I tried following the instructions from the accepted answer from that link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To locally ignore the file:

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```