# Git Ignored File Delete by Mistake

Tags: git

I have an ignored file in .gitignore but I'm delete the file with:

**git rm --cached myFile**

And push to remote repository by mistake. When I sent pull-request its file display deleted file. I use the update-index command:

**git update-index --assume-unchanged myFile**

Return to me this error:
**fatal: Unable to mark file myFile**

How to add this file repository and ignore changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Comment: I tried this solution but it's not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may try editing history and removing commits from the remote (push --force). You have to ensure noone else ever got that extra commit or else you'd ask for quite a bit of trouble.

Use `git rebase -i` and work it out (-i means interactive). Then use `git push --force` to actually upload that change (--force is needed as those changed commits override old ones)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem:

- Once should be remove the file from **.gitignore** file
- Create the myFile and add to git with this command: **git add myFile**
- Commit the file change: **git commit -am "added myFile file**
- At least untrack the file: **git update-index --assume-unchanged myFile**

So now this file is not deleted from repository and ignored any changes.

Thanks for -1 reputation ;)