# Does GitKraken ignore the git exclude file?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I use GitKraken for my version control needs and for the most part I enjoy it. Every now and then I do run across something that I can do the UI and have to use the commandline.

One thing I am attempting to do right now is to add some file patterns into my git repo's **.git/info/exclude** file (NOTE: This is not git ignore; I'm just trying to exlcude changes in my local repo since the files in question are not relevant to what needs to be committed.)

GitKraken seems to be ignoring the changes I've made to this file, or I'm simply not doing it correctly. Does anyone know if GitKraken does anything with this file? I can't seem to find any documentation on their website regarding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The exclude and ignore are slightly different. I also don't want to ignore and stop tracking because that will actually remove it from the repo, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, it should honor it.  What do you think is different about the `info/exclude` and `gitignore` files?  They both only work on _untracked_ files.

Comment: You could use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/1615903 The only difference with exclude file and .gitignore file is that exclude file is on your local repo only. Both only work for untracked files, and it's not specific to GitKraken.

Comment: I am having the same issue. After adding patterns to .git/info/exclude, gitkraken shows a different status than the CLI `git status`. To me this indicates that gitkraken is not honoring the exclude file, and it makes me wonder whether gitkraken doesn't make use of the same git program as the CLI.