# How to stop tracking changes to web.config file after the initial commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to tell git to stop tracking changes to the web.config file after the initial commit?
I've got a .gitignore file with *.config in it. But since I committed the web.config file on the initial check in, any time I make change to web.config file it keeps track of it.
But if i add a second config file it does ignore that file..

I want to be able to ignore any changes I make to the first web.config file as well.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To make `git` stop tracking the `web.config` completely including the initial commit.**

`git` does not ignore a file that has already been tracked before a rule was added to `.gitignore` file to ignore it.

In such a case the file must be un-tracked first with this command: `git rm --cached <filename>`.

So if you are trying to ignore this file after the initial commit, run this: `git rm --cached web.config`, and you should be good to go.

**To make `git` stop tracking future changes in `web.config`, apart from the initial commit.**

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/can-i-git-commit-a-file-and-ignore-its-content-changes) answer as mentioned by @phd.