# git ignore changes to file until next change

Tags: git

Is there a variation on `git update-index --skip-worktree` that will make the file be treated as unchanged *but only until the next time the file is modified*?

In other words, I'm looking for a self-cancelling `--skip-worktree` equivalent.

My motivation is that I've made some changes that I don't want ever to commit. But if I ever make any *further* changes to the same file I want it immediately to reappear in the list of modified files so that I am prompted to consider if the new changes should be committed. If I use `git update-index --skip-worktree` then I am likely to forget.

(There are lots of similar questions and answers but none of them describe a 'self-cancelling' method, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320183/127670.)

Comment: *"I've made some changes to a file that I don't want ever to commit."* -- either the file should be in `.gitignore` (and never added to the repo) or the changes should stay in a different file (that is ignored by Git).

Comment: "until the next time the file is modified" - you mean, modified by local user?

Comment: because `--skip-worktree`, I believe, should be removed if the file has changed remotely and you checkout the new version.

Comment: I'd look at [clean filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code)

Comment: @max630 I mean primarily until modified by the user. It's to stop me forgetting to commit changes that *should* be pushed in the file. Obviously if the file is modified remotely it needs to do something sane, like pull in the remote changes and (try to) merge with the local version. Whether that triggers the 'self-cancelling' doesn't really matter.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Vincent No, I don't think it's possible.