# Merging local changes for a git repo without committing in new branches

Tags: git, settings

When I'm working on a project, sometimes my machine requires specific changes to a config file or two, or many.  Currently, I have these changes stored in a local branch: `local-settings`.

Then, when I need to do a bug fix and test, I do a pull from remote and get latest.  I create my `new-branch` and then I merge `local-settings` into `new-branch` and do a `git reset HEAD~1` to "undo" the merge commit.  From there I only stage and commit my bug fix files.

Is there any damage with doing things this way, and is there a better way of persisting local changes that I need long-term?  I've seen other questions mention `git stash`, but that wipes out the stashed changes once they are popped, correct?  That doesn't seem like a good solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: IMO this kind of local history manipulation is normal and expected in git, though stash is easier for simple use cases (harder to make a mistake like reset something you didn't mean to). It's possible to pop a stash without deleting it: `git apply`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I 'git commit' a file and ignore its content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/can-i-git-commit-a-file-and-ignore-its-content-changes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it the opposite way : instead of always merging your `local-settings` (which pollute your history) into `new-branch`, just rebase your `local-settings` and develop bugfix on it (assuming `local-settings` derives from `new branch`. Otherwise, `cherry-pick` could help). Then, when completed, `stash` your work, switch to `new-branch` and `stash pop`. After that, `commit` the bugfix into `new branch`.

That way you always develop on your `local-settings` branch, but commit changes in `new-branch`.

**EDIT**

If your `local-settings` branch have more than a single commit, you can use `rebase --onto` :

Let's say you've named your branches like so:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (new-branch)
 \-- E -- G -- H -- I -- J (current-parent)
      \-- K -- L (local-branch)
```

What you want to do is rebase my-branch onto the D commit like so:

```
git rebase current-parent local-branch --onto D
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because `local-settings` is branched way before `new-branch` and typically only contains a few changes to a file or two.  `cherry-pick` could work if I only keep one commit in `local-settings` though, but sometimes I have multiple commits there.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Updated answer.