# Git - Have untracked files in online repository

Tags: git, git-index, git-untracked

I'm using git (bitbucket) to source control my linux configuration files. All the files are in the directory `~/.cfg/`. Then I additionally have some local configuration files in `~/.cfg/local/` which are supposed to be different from machine to machine.

I would like to keep a copy of the local files in my online repository as a kind of sample local config but would like to otherwise not track the files.  I don't really care whether they get cloned with `git clone` though, either way is fine.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/5769814) but that removes the files from the online repository.

I also tried the solution outlined in [this blog post](https://www.christianengvall.se/untrack-files-local-repository-keep-origin-git/), which worked better, but unfortunately has 2 drawbacks: 1) it has to be repeated on each machine and 2) it does not actually unfollow the files. So if I ever accidentally upload a local config from some machine (forgetting to run the command from the post), the next `git pull` on any other machine will override that machine's local configuration.

---

To summarize, I would like a solution that does the following:

1. It keeps the initial upload of the entire `~/.cfg/` (including `~/.cfg/local/`) in the online repository.
2. It pushes the contents of `~/.cfg/` but not the contents of `~/.cfg/local/` whenever I do the standard `git add -A; git commit -m "asdf"; git push`
3. It pulls the contents of `~/.cfg/` but not the contents of `~/.cfg/local/` when I `git pull`.

Comment: you should look at using .gitignore files which specify the cfg files and folder.  Have you tried?

Comment: I have a `.gitignore` with `/local/*` in it, but that doesn't stop tracking my local files, unless I also use the `git rm` command from the linked answer (which removes the files from the online repository).

Comment: I think the answer from that post is the same as the 2nd solution I linked to in mine.

Comment: [This answers specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319626/1615903) is the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like a solution that does [things Git can't do]

Sorry, but the answer is: **No, Git can't do that.**  You can get *close*, but it's not fun: it requires work on the part of everyone who runs `git clone`, and from then on there are repeated encounters that can cause burns.  That's why the standard method is the one recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319626/1256452) to [Can I 'git commit' a file and ignore its content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3319479/1256452)

It may help to understand *why* Git can't do that.  Let's look more specifically at what "that" is:

> - keep the initial upload of the entire `~/.cfg/` (including `~/.cfg/local/`) in the online repository.

This, you *can* do.  But the phrasing is odd, because Git does not store *files*.  Git stores *commits*, which *contain* files.  That might seem like mere semantics, but then again, it's "mere semantics" as to whether "hot" water is nice for a shower (40˚C / 104˚F: hot, but not scalding), or will give you second-degree burns (95˚C / 203˚F: near boiling, at standard pressure).

So, you *can* have a commit that contains files including `cfg/foo` and `cfg/local/bar`.  So far, no real problem—the main problem is that you cannot have a commit that contains an empty directory `cfg/local/`, as Git stores only the file themselves in each commit, not the containing directory: it assumes that anyone *using* the repository later will create directories automatically as needed, whenever there's a file to be stored, whose name forces that future / other Git to call `os.mkdir` or whatever it is that creates a directory to contain that file.

> - push the contents of `~/.cfg/` but not the contents of `~/.cfg/local/` whenever I do the standard `git add -A; git commit -m "asdf"; git push`

Here's the first problem, where those "mere" semantics are at least a little scalding: Git doesn't push *files*.  Git pushes *commits*.

You have three commands here.  The first one, `git add -A`, tells Git: *Update the index copy of all files that are recorded in the index, by replacing it with a fresh version from my work-tree.*  The second one, `git commit`, tells Git: *Make a new commit using the files that are stored in the index.*  The third, `git push`, tells Git: *Send some commit(s) to some other Git, then ask that other Git to set one or more of its references, such as its `refs/heads/master`—its `master` branch—to some hash-ID.*

This brings in this new term, *the index*, and that's where the trouble starts.

If your `cfg/local/bar` file is in your index, it will be in your commits.  If it is *not* in your index, it will *not* be in your commits.  That's as simple as it gets, but its implications are nasty:

- You can *remove* the file from your index without touching the work-tree version (`git rm --cached cfg/local/bar`), but this is going to cause a future problem.
- Or, you can set the `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree` bits on the copy of the file that's *in* your index.  This is almost good enough, but not quite.  (Incidentally, the two are more or less equivalent, but "skip worktree" is the one that's intended for this kind of use—except that its true intent is really for use in sparse checkout.  I'll write "skip worktree" below but this really means either one.)

Setting the bit requires that you run a command manually after `git clone`.  The index is private to *your* copy of the repository, so everyone who runs `git clone` must run this `git update-index` command too, at least once, right after `git clone`.  (Git will not let you automate this through Git itself, though of course you can write a script to do it and distribute the script.)

As you've probably already seen, this only *almost* works.

> - pull the contents of `~/.cfg/` but not the contents of `~/.cfg/local/` when I `git pull`

Once again, Git will burn you here.  The problem is that `git pull` is not really a thing of its own: it means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the *second* Git command is going to cause trouble.

The second Git command is normally `git merge`, and we'll assume for now that it is.  The other option, `git rebase`, is *worse* for you, as rebase is essentially repeated `git cherry-pick` with each cherry-pick operation itself being a merge, resulting in *multiple* merges.

Merges, like commits, happen in or through the index.  Git loads *all* the files from *three* commits into the index, pairing up files in two separate steps (base vs "ours", and base vs theirs), and then combining the pairings.  So this merges each file that's in the index, or, if a file that *was* in the index in an earlier commit *isn't* in the index now, *removes or renames* files.

This means that if a file `cfg/local/bar` exists in the merge base commit and in "their" commit—and it will need to be there, if you want an initial `git clone` to populate `cfg/local` with `cfg/local/bar`—then it needs to exist in the "ours" commit as well, otherwise Git will insist on *removing* it to keep our change.  That, in turn, means that if they have changed *their* copy in *their* commit, Git will want to apply their change to your copy in your commit too.

If you've used `git update-index` to fuss with the `--skip-worktree` flag, you've been re-committing the original version of `cfg/local/bar` all along.  The flag just tells Git: *Hey, don't look at my own version of this file, just assume that the copy in the index is still correct.*  This affects the `git add -A` step: instead of *Update all files that are listed in the index*, it actually does: *Update all files that aren't specially marked.*  You can change `cfg/local/bar` all you like, and `git add -A` will *skip over* the update: it won't copy your work-tree `cfg/local/bar` back into the index, instead keeping the copy it put into the index back when you first had `git clone` run `git checkout` for you.

So all of *your* commits have a `cfg/local/bar`, but the *contents* these commits store *in* that `cfg/local/bar`, in each commit, are the same contents you got when you ran `git clone`, even if you've changed the work-tree copy.  Your skip-worktree bit told your Git to just leave the index copy of `cfg/local/bar` alone, which it has done.

But now that it's *merge time*, and *they* have changed *their* `cfg/local/bar` for whatever reason—the reason doesn't matter, what matters is that they *did* change it—*now* your Git is faced with the job of combining your changes (none) with their changes (some).  It does so by taking the only changes—theirs, of course—and *now* your Git will insist on *copying* the updated `cfg/local/bar` out into your work-tree.  This will *overwrite your `cfg/local/bar`*, and that's the pain point: that's where this approach burns you.

If *they* **never** (not ever, not once) change their `cfg/local/bar`, this approach—setting skip-worktree—*will* actually work.  But that depends on the kindness of strangers, or at least, on the idea that the local config in `cfg/local/bar` in *every commit ever* be exactly the same ... in which case, what was the point of committing it at all?

But if they ever do change it, you'll get burned (mild or otherwise) when you merge their change with your lack-of-change, because Git will want to overwrite your `cfg/local/bar` with their updated one.

The alternative, in which you *remove* your `cfg/local/bar` from your index early on, is worse: now every commit *you* push *doesn't have the file at all*.  Git views this as a command: *When going from a commit that does have the file, to one that doesn't have the file, remove the file.*  So if you take this approach, *you're* the one who changed the file!  You told everyone else: *Remove this file!*

The *only* truly, 100% guaranteed, correct way to deal with this is: **Never commit the file in the first place.**  If *every* commit in the repository *doesn't* have `cfg/local/bar`, that file will *never* be put into the index.  If that name is listed in a `.gitignore` as well, no automatic "add all files" will *add* it to the index, so it won't be in *future* commits.  That means it won't be in there when you start, nor when you finish.  Git will never want to merge it, nor overwrite your copy of it.  It will always be an untracked-and-ignored file, existing in your work-tree, but not in any of your commits.

Of course, this means there's a little bit of initial pain: every time you run `git clone <url>` you must also do: `cp -r .cfg/local-committed/ .cfg/local`.  But if you were going to use `--skip-worktree`, then every time you run `git clone <url>` you must follow that immediately with `git update-index --skip-worktree .cfg/local/bar`.  So it's *exactly the same amount of pain* as the bad alternative, without any of its badness.

Moreover, if you're in control of the software, you can set up the software so that, if `.cfg/local/` does not exist when you first *run* the program, the program *creates* `.cfg/local/` by copying from `.cfg/local-committed/`.  Then that pain of "first setup" goes away too!  **That's why committing the default configuration into a separate file, that the user either manually or automatically *copies* to the local configuration file, which remains an untracked file forever, is the correct solution.**

Comment: Thank you, this is a very detailed explanation and an interesting read. Your quote "Git doesn't push files. Git pushes commits." (which is kind of the gist of the entire post) is particularly important to understand in this situation. The solution you outlined in your last paragraph seems like the optimal one and is the one I'll be using.