# Cannot git pull due to conflict with local excluded file

Tags: git

I have a config file I have excluded locally. I did not use `.gitignore` because other team members update the file, but my local changes only apply to my machine. I used this question for reference on how to exclude the file: [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally/1753078#1753078)

A team member has updated the file, and I'm now unable to do a git pull. I get the error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    config/td_config.php
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

But my local shows no changes to `td_config.php` because it is excluded. I cannot commit or stash it.

My questions are:

1. Why does the remote see local changes to a file I've excluded when my expectation is that the remote will not be aware of changes to an excluded file?
2. How do I get around this problem?

I tried
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged config/td_config.php`
to no avail.

Comment: Looks like I need additional clarification on this:

It's been a while since I set up the local ignore so I don't recall the exact process I used. But I do currently have that file in my .git/info/exclude.

You're right that I'm unclear on the differences between assume-unchanged, skip-worktree, and the exclude file, but it still looks to me like the conflict I'm seeing isn't the behavior I expect from having something excluded.

I'm using Tower as a gui for this, partially so I can avoid commands I don't understand.

Comment: `.git/info/exclude` can't be used to ignore changes to tracked files, either. It's exactly like `.gitignore`, except it isn't tracked or shared. It's for local ignores, but just like `.gitignore` it only prevents files from being tracked in the first place, having no effect on tracked files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the remote see local changes to a file I've excluded when my expectation is that the remote will not be aware of changes to an excluded file?

Because [that's not what `assume-unchanged` does](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqy4z5go1y.fsf@gitster.dls.corp.google.com/); in fact, it's for the very opposite purpose (bold added):

> Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism.  It
>   is "I know my filesystem operations are slow.  **I'll promise Git that
>   I won't change these paths by making them with that bit---that way,
>   Git does not have to check if I changed things in there every time I
>   ask for 'git status' output".**  It does not mean anything other than
>   that.  Especially, it is *not* a promise by Git that Git will always
>   consider these paths are unmodified---if Git can determine a path
>   that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring
>   extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path
>   *has been* modified (as a result, "git commit -a" is free to commit
>   that change).

Yes, there are lots of resources recommending `assume-unchanged` to ignore local changes to a tracked file. They're almost all wrong, and the issue you're asking about is one of the ways that this can fail.

Unfortunately, `assume-unchanged` often looks like it's ignoring changes to files so people continue to use it and to recommend it.

> How do I get around this problem?

[`skip-worktree` is a better option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/354577), but it's not a perfect fit either. A much better solution is to coordinate with your team to [rename the tracked file to `td_config.template.php` or similar and properly ignore `td_config.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319626/354577).

Don't fight Git; use it the way it's meant to be used. It doesn't provide a mechanism for ignoring a tracked file, and all of the current workarounds are flawed in one way or another.

(If you really want to ignore this advice, you should be able to `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` the file, then stash your changes, then pull, then apply your changes, then re-apply the bit. But do so knowing that it *doesn't do what you want it to*.)

**Edit:**

OP commented that

> When I originally set this up, I tried update-index, skip-worktree, and the exclude file… so at this point it's pretty hard to understand how exactly git is or isn't tracking the file.

Running `git ls-files -v config/td_config.php` helps us figure out which of these settings is active on that file. In this case we got

```
S config/td_config.php
```

The capital S shows us that [`skip-worktree` is set](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt-S), and that [`assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--v) is unset on the file. Running `git update-index --no-skip-worktree config/td_config.php` should return it to "regular status", at which point any of the preceding suggestions can be used.

Comment: As my question mentions, I tried the update-index --no-assume-unchanged command but I am still unable to pull.

When I originally set this up, I tried update-index, skip-worktree, and the exclude file (with little understanding of what they actually did, clearly), so at this point it's pretty hard to understand how exactly git is or isn't tracking the file.

Pretty sure my team doesn't want to take the time to rework our workflow, so I have to find a workaround myself.

Comment: @TonyChapman, yes, I saw that. Based on what you've shared so far I'm not sure what the issue is; I had hoped I could convince you to use a more appropriate workflow. I still don't recommend abusing `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` this way, and I really think you should propose this change to your team. In any case, I'd like to help you solve your immediate issue if possible. What does `git ls-files -v config/td_config.php` give?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that.

I've learned so far that git has no way to natively do _exactly_ what I want, which is to pull changes from the remote but ignore changes I make locally. I can raise the workflow issue with the team at a later point (as this issue affects other files I work with also) but need to move past it now.

My local changes are trivial, so I can easily delete the file, pull and reproduce my configuration. Not sure what is best after that.

The output you requested is:
```S config/td_config.php```

Comment: Okay, that capital `S` means that [`skip-worktree` is set](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt-S) and [`assume-unchanged` is not](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--v). Try running `git update-index --no-skip-worktree config/td_config.php`, then `git stash save "Stash local config changes"`, pull your changes, then `git stash pop`. Then, if you must, `git update-index --skip-worktree config/td_config.php` to mark it with the `skip-worktree` bit again.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I'll update my answer with the `ls-files -v` bit for completeness.

Comment: Incidentally, I wrote a program, `git-flagged`, to identify files in the index with either or both of skip-worktree or assume-unchanged set. It's in my general purpose scripts repository at https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged (it also has an option to clear such flags).

Answer (score 0):

Stash the file then pull
`git stash`
`git pull`
`git stash pop`

Comment: This will not work because locally git does not recognize any changes to the file, which is the behavior I want.

Comment: Copy the file to another directory, `git checkout <filename>`, `git pull`, then copy file back?