# Ignore line in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

The .gitignore of a project (maintained by someone else) is like this:

```
.idea/*
!.idea/watcherTasks.xml
```

I want to add private watcher tasks, so my watcherTasks.xml is changed. But I don't want to commit it.

I don't want to type `git reset .idea/watcherTasks.xml` (or specify the paths) every time I `git add`/`git commit`. So I tried to use .git/info/exclude to ignore the file locally:

```
.idea/watcherTasks.xml
```

However, the .git/info/exclude line cannot override the .gitignore line (probably because `!` has higher priority).

Is there something I can put in .git/info/exclude to cancel the effect of the `!.idea/watcherTasks.xml` line in .gitignore? I don't want to modify the .gitignore since I do not maintain the project.

**This question does not ask for approaches like `git commit $path`, because I do not want to change future commit commands to use.**

Comment: .gitignore has no effect if the file is already committed / added to the repo.

Comment: @SOFe The current selected answer, while technically correct, does not address your problem: I have proposed an actual solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I 'git commit' a file and ignore its content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/can-i-git-commit-a-file-and-ignore-its-content-changes)

Comment: @1615903 this question specifically asks *without specifying options in each add/commit command*. While the linked question also has relevant answers, this question has a more specific requirement such that most answers there would not suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.idea/watcherTasks.xml` is already tracked, you can:

- modify it locally
- make sure it remains *not* added/committed with

  ```
  cd /root/folder/of/your/local/repository
  git update-index --skip-worktree -- .idea/watcherTasks.xml
  ```

That means:

- no need to override an ignore rule
- no need to modify a `.gitignore`

Your tracked file remains tracked, but none of your local modification will be added or committed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking (summarized: to ignore an ignore rule), the answer is No. In the .gitignore documentation: [https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignor](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)e it clearly states the following:

A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected;

Now, as you note, you do not want to affect the overall repository. So, I think you are out of luck on this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this using # and it worked.

Before...

```
public_html/includes/local.php
```

local.php is ignored, but when I changed it to...

```
#public_html/includes/local.php
```

local.php is there.

I can see no error warnings on my github desktop, nor on the site itself.