# how to not pull a file that commited?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

I have a zip file (contains jdk) that is already committed to the remote repo,
**I only use this file in the remote repo** (as a cicd procedure)

and what I want is that **I will not be able to pull it** (the zip file) from the remote,
because in my local repo I have no use in it.

I think it's like the opposite to `git rm --cached` because what I need is the file to **stay in the remote and not be in the local**.

I found this thread [Ignore changes to a file that is already committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026709/ignore-changes-to-a-file-that-is-already-committed) but i did not understand it that much.

Does anybody know how I can *not* pull the file?

Comment: Git doesn't pull files.

Comment: what do you mean? of course it pull, i meant when i updated my local repo with the remote i don't want to pull the zip file

Comment: My advice. Don't keep the zip in the repo.

Comment: why does it matter? the problem is relevant to any type of file

Comment: Git doesn't pull files. It pulls commits (and the objects that go with them). --- If you would like the remote to keep the file, but remove them locally, this will have to be done after _every pull_. Don't commit the removal though, otherwise it will remove the remote repo file on the next push.

Comment: Now I understand what you were saying about the pull, and you also said here my problem that I do not want that "remove them locally" to happen after every pull. But I want to do is to address this problem like a .gitignore that ignore certain files, then I will have something similar for the files I want to ignore that are already in the commit.

Comment: You can't ignore files that are already committed.

Comment: well, it solve my problem in a workaround with your advice, I decided to put the jdk in other branch(not the master), then I use this branch only for the jdk and for the actual development I am using the master as usual. so I am using 2 branches and it solve it. thanks!

Comment: Just never merge that branch into the others. Otherwise you’ll be back to square one