# PyCharm - "one-way" Git ignore?

Tags: git, pycharm

I have a file that I want to update (e.g. change it while I do git pull), but never upload (e.g. when I do git commit), or at least don't upload it "by default" with almost all commits (but I may have some temporary local changes). How can I do this in PyCharm? I'm using it since inspecting commit changes with GUI is easier for me and I'm pretty sure it has an option for this.

Comment: It doesn't because GIt cannot do that. Git doesn't push files — it pushes commit. Once a file is tracked it is in all commits; there is no way to commit a file but not push it.

Comment: @phd ok, so how can I protect file from being commited, while at the same time receiving new changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+file+ignore+changes