# Ignore content changes to file after pushed to git repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file `users.csv` which is pushed to the repository. This csv file gets updated every time the test suite is run.

- I don't want the file to be shown as modified in my local machine
  every time the test suite is run. In that case i assume i can use the
  command

  ```
  git update-index --assume-unchanged [<file> ...]
  ```

Ref: [Can I 'git commit' a file and ignore its content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/can-i-git-commit-a-file-and-ignore-its-content-changes)

- Now, assume that another developer pulled all the changes that i pushed. **When the test suite is run on his machine, the same csv should not show as modified and the file should be still there in his machine.**

I assume adding the file in .gitignore will not help since the file is already tracked.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the test suite should:

- copy `users.csv` to `user.csv.test` (with `user.csv.test` in the `.gitignore`, so left as a private file)
- modify `user.csv.test`

That way, you don't have to manage `update-index` on each developer repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Git specifically doesn't offer a way to ignore changes to tracked files.  This is [thoroughly answered in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

You are correct that `.gitignore` has no effect on files that are already tracked.

There are a couple ways you can avoid having a problem here.  The first is to use a temporary directory (or an ignored directory like `test/tmp`) for your test suite input and output to avoid this being a problem.  This is what Git does and several other projects do as well.

You could also leave the file `users.csv` ignored and move the real file to a different location, and then copy it into place before use.  Then, if the test suite modifies it, it won't be a problem on development systems.