# Managing phonegap / cordova project with git

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, cordova

What's the best practise for managing a phonegap project in git?

Currently I have the www folder as a git repository, but the iPhone version of phonegap adds a phonegap.js into that folder and I don't want to commit that because it is iPhone specific (I want to share the repo between the different platforms). I'm also worried that I am probably putting the .git folder onto the phone (which is a complete waste of space).

Also, should I be minifying all my code before bundling it into the app (e.g. with [uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)). How can I keep the unminified code in git, and have XCode's build and run command (for the iPhone version) minifiy it before copying it to the phone?

What about Eclipse/Android?

**Edit** This question is highly outdated now, based on older versions of phonegap. Cordova cli and corodva 3 have changed the landscape completely (for the better). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911204/gitignore-for-phonegap-cordova-3-0-projects-what-should-i-commit).

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the automatic generation of phonega.js.

- On the left panel of XCode go to Targets -> Your App
- Double on "Copy Phonegap Javascript" and modify it according to your needs.

Then you can also modify all the other shell scripts or add your own scripts to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In term of release management, Git shouldn't be in the picture (unless, as you mention in your question, you want to end up with a `.git` on the phone).

The build step should output the minifyied code outside of the Git repo, and then build and deploy.

As for the `phonegap.js`, if it is platform specific, it could be added to a `.gitignore` file (don't forget to [contribute back to the `gitignore` project](https://github.com/github/gitignore)), while keeping a:

- `phonegap.js.template` file
- `phonegap.js.value1` for the phone-specific values
- `phonegap.js.value2` for the another platform-specific values
- a script able to generate the right (private) `phonegap.js` file depending on the current platform.
  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318043/mark-a-file-in-the-git-repo-as-temporarily-ignored/3318202#3318202) for instance: that script can be the `smudge` step of a custom filter driver)

Comment: I probably should have emphasized XCode more in the question. How do I configure XCode to work efficently with phonegap and git? Phonegap.js is generated for me by Phonegap, it doesn't need to be templated in any repository.

Comment: @rjmunro: ok, I didn't fully grasp the right scope of your question ;) But the first part is still relevant.