# Can files platforms/*/www folder be ignored in Cordova?

Tags: cordova

I'm fairly new to Cordova/PhoneGap, and if I understand correctly the contents of the `www/` folder are copied to the `/platforms/` folder as part of the build. So whenever I edit `index.html` and build for iOS, the `/platforms/ios/www/index.html` file gets updated.

Can `/platforms/*/www/` be safely ignored? For example, via the `.gitignore` file? Or are there situations where I would edit files under `/platforms/ios/www` rather than in `/www`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore these folders. Definitely do not check the files in to repo since (as you already pointed out) they are replicates.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your www folder in root folder, outside of platforms folder. This folder automatically copy to /platforms/ios/www/ directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is, is it safe to .gitignore the `/platforms/ios/www/` directory? Will that directory be recreated every time I build? Or should I check those files into my repository?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911204/gitignore-for-phonegap-cordova-3-0-projects-what-should-i-commit