# Cordova project and git

Tags: git, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am very new to github, so this is probably a dumb question.  I have a cordova project that I've created a repository for.  The "www" folder was added to source when I created the repository.  I used "git add .", but it won't add my "platforms" or "plugins" folders and their contents.  All three folders are on the same level. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: git add ./platforms doesn't work?

Comment: Those folders may be listed in the `.gitignore` file (if any), which would prevent your from staging them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in "[`.gitignore` for PhoneGap/Cordova 3.0 projects - what should I commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146656/6309)":

> I like the idea of omitting the platforms directory.
>   In fact, I am am able to exclude both the `plugins` and `platforms` directories.
>   A good starting point for the `.gitignore`:

```
platforms/
plugins/
```

Note that a [standard .gitignore for such directoves](https://github.com/crilleengvall/gitignore/blob/master/Phonegap.gitignore) (as [Jubobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jubobs) suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206693/cordova-project-and-git/27209012#comment42898155_27206693)), since the `plugin` folder, for instance, would be populated by the command `cordova plugin add ...`.