# Get file out of git repo and git ignore it without deleting it from filesystem

Tags: git

So, a config file somehow made its way into our git repo that we don't want there.  But we do want it on our individual systems.

Is there a way to get the file out of the repo without causing the file to get deleted from individual repos when our team members do a pull?

Many thanks!

Comment: It does seem like a flaw in the Git philosophy, but I don't believe there's any way to do this.  You can certainly remove a file from the repository without removing it from your working directory (`git rm --cached`), but whenever people do a pull, that file will get deleted, as you know.  You might be out of luck....

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318043/mark-a-file-in-the-git-repo-as-temporarily-ignored?rq=1

Comment: Send emails to your folks and tell them to backup that file before pulling (cough...) And install pre-receive hook (http://criticallog.thornet.net/2011/06/02/running-php-linter-before-pushing-changes-to-a-git-repository/ ) to prevent such thing from happending again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove it from repository (not working tree) using

```
git rm --cached
```

and tell your coworkers to do a backup in the first time they sync (pull) their repositories, because git will delete it.
Otherwise, even the file being present on `.gitignore`, git will always detect changes when the file does part of the repository.