# How could I backup/version control my file (having IDE settings) at some other path in git?

Tags: git, windows-10, bitbucket

I might not have explained my question well so let me give an example.

I am on `windows10` and I am using `Bitbucket` for version control and backup.

My IDE, `Intellij` has a `workspace.xml` file which contains some configurations to run a build. Its path is say `baseDir/something/something/.idea/workspace.xml`. I want to back it/version control it so that when I move to a new work station, I can override the default `workspace.xml` with this one and have all my configurations.

Is it possible that I back up the `workspace.xml` file at a path other than `baseDir/something/something/.idea/workspace.xml` in Bitbucket eg. `baseDir/IDESettings/idea/workspace.xml`?

If I change `baseDir/something/something/.idea/workspace.xml` on my local machine (say add or change a new build configuration), a new version should get created in `baseDir/IDESettings/idea/workspace.xml` and I move to a new machine and install the IntelliJ IDE then the `workspace.xml` from `baseDir/IDESettings/idea/workspace.xml` should be used.

I am guessing that I might have to use symbolic links but I would appreciate if someone could confirm this or suggest an alternative.

Comment: Why does it have to be backed up then version controlled?  Couldn't you just commit `.idea/workspace.xml`?

Comment: sorry, I meant the same thing. Basically commit `workspace.xml` but not in `.idea/`, rather at some other path.

Comment: Well that's what my question is actually. Why not just commit it under `.idea/` as is?

Comment: Because I am afraid that on a new machine, when I'll download the repo, I'll get `.idea/workspace.xml` as well. Now when I'll import the project in the IDE (in my new machine), IDE will probably override the existing `.idea/workspace.xml`

Comment: Yeah, but after you import it, if the IDE changes it, you can always just check it out from the repo. I don't think the IDE would overwrite it again until you actually change something.

Answer (score 0):

> or suggest an alternative.

Use a content filter driver (**[smudge/clean process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293383/hide-a-string-in-a-file-before-git-commit/2294246#2294246)**), as mentioned in "[GameMaker Studio 2 collaboration between windows and osx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459674/6309)"

The `smudge` script can apply to any file in your repo, and generate automatically on `git checkout` a private (non-tracked file) like `baseDir/something/something/.idea/workspace.xml`, depending on your machine.

The clean script would on `git commit` save that private file in your Git repo file.